# How to selectively delete header lines from a .csv file using Windows batching (cmd)?

Tags: batch-file

I am new to CMD batching and I am writing a small script that should take a file containing a list of .csv files and remove the header of every file except for two lines. One of the lines to keep contains the word "Timestamp", it looks like this: 
"Timestamp: 2013-10-31T16:26:48.0110000". 
The other line to keep signals the end of the header and it always starts with "Time(ms)" as the first token.
      Initially I assumed the header to be of constant size (lines 1-20) and just kept line 2 and 20. Now I need my script to actually detect the end of the header as there are files with a 24-lines header.
       Here is the script as it is right now

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment
setlocal
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (list.txt) do (
  findstr /n "^" "%%a"|repl "^(1|10|11|12|1?[3456789]):" ":"|repl "^\d+:" "" A      >"%%a.new" 
 move /y "%%a.new" "%%a" >nul
 )
```

Credits to @dbenham who helped a lot to wrote the first script in an answer to a previous question and publish an utility named repl.bat.

Thanks in advance

David RODRIGUEZ

Comment: Your files are not plain .CSV files if there is a 24 line header.  You will have to show some sample data before the task will be clear .

Comment: Here is an example taken from one file (several header lines)                              Description:,
Timestamp:,2013-10-31T16:26:59.9610000                                      
Duration:,10092
Time(ms),X,Y,Z
0.0000,-0.39423999004066,-0.177099995780736,-0.414200004190207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that should be robust.  It uses a tool called `findrepl.bat` which is a grep-like tool written in a manner similar to `repl.bat`.

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
   type "%%a"|findrepl "^" /e:"^Time\(ms\)" /b:"Timestamp" >"%%a.new"
   type "%%a"|findrepl "^Time\(ms\)" /o:0:999999 >>"%%a.new"
   move /y "%%a.new" "%%a" >nul
)
pause
```

This assumes that `Time(ms)` is in column 1 and in theory it will handle files with up to 1 million lines.

Comment: Thanks very much foxidrive, it worked great! I used "^Timestamp" instead of "Timestamp" to get rid ot some lines that also contained "Timestamp" in the middle. Now, if I want to use "^Time\(ms\)" to mark the end of the header without keeping that line, what should I do (my question was not well formulated, my bad)? Thanks again!

Comment: Change `/o:0:999999` to `/o:1:999999` to eliminate the last line of the header (which is the first line of the second compare).  Not tested but let me know if it isn't right.